# Consulta de interes por fechas menos fecha de pago total

Tags: mysql

espero ser mas claro ahora, tengo la siguiente tabla "detallepre".

```
 Cuota  FechaCuota  FechaPago   Capital  Interes  Estado  
------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  --------
     1  2018-05-07  2018-05-07  722.62   265.78         -1
     2  2018-06-06  2018-06-06  741.67   246.73         -1
     3  2018-07-06  2018-07-07  768.64   219.76         -1
     4  2018-08-05  2018-07-07  2305.92  400.00         -1
     5  2018-09-04  2018-07-07  5543.42  646.63         -1
```

Donde FechaCuota es la fecha programada para pagar y FechaPago es la fecha que se realizo el pago, según la tabla la 1 y 2 cuota se pago en la fecha programada y la 3,4 y 5 cuota se pago el mismo dia el 2018-07-07, fue el pago total de intereses, el Estado es -1 para Pagado y 1 para Deuda.
Quiero obtener la sumatoria de Interes hasta el cierre de mes que yo indique, con una excepcion que explicare al final.
Por ejemplo si consulto el hasta el mes de Junio, uso la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Interes),0) Interes FROM detallepre WHERE FechaCuota <= '2018-06-30'
```

resultado: **512.51** Correcto

Consulta hasta Julio:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Interes),0) Interes FROM detallepre WHERE FechaCuota <= '2018-07-30'
```

resultado: **732.27** Correcto

Consulta hasta Agosto, aquí es donde tengo problema.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Interes),0) Interes FROM detallepre WHERE FechaCuota <= '2018-08-30'
```

resultado: **1132.27** Incorrecto (digo incorrecto por que no es el resultado esperado)

Lo que espero obtener es **732.27** ya que la fecha de pago total (cuando se pagaron todas las cuotas restantes) fue en julio el 2018-07-07, y no deberia de seguir sumando el interes ya que estan pagadas las cuotas, como deberia de modificar mi sql en el ultimo caso para conseguir lo que necesito. Gracias

Comment: Con el ejemplo que diste, no se como llegas a esos numero... o sea.. no me suma de ninguna forma, el campo fecha no existe en tu ejemplo...

Comment: Ya lo actualize

Comment: Ok. Igual la ultima consulta trae el valor correcto. No se entiende tu ultima frase, como se sabe que se pagaron las cuotas restantes? vos estas sumando esa columna hasta ese dia. Capaz falta informacion?

Comment: Se sabe que se pagó por el estado y por la fecha de pago, cuanto no esta pagado tiene la fecha por default de 0001-01-01 y estado deuda.

Comment: Eso lo sabes vos, no nosotros. Igual sigue siendo poco claro. Si todas dicen pagadas no podes filtrar por ahi. Queres filtrar por fechapago? No queda claro cuales son tus filtros. Pulsa el boton [edit] y explica claramento como es que queres filtrar esto. Tal vez para vos resulte claro, pero no lo explicaste.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, lo edite otra vez espero ser mas claro.

Comment: Si me queda claro... pero lo que queres no es solamente un and fechacuota < fechapago?

Comment: Claro de esa forma me sale el resultado esperado, pero como haria una consulta sql, donde yo solo pase la fecha hasta donde quiero tener la información x ejmplo un sp donde me pida la variable fecha.
Si ingreso la fecha 2018-06-30 el resultado sea 512.51
Si ingreso la fecha 2018-07-30 el resultado sea 732.27
Si ingreso la fecha 2018-08-30 el resultado sea 732.27

Comment: Y ahora no te entiendo de vuelta. La consulta q tenes mas la otra clausula no te devuelve siempre lo que queres?

Comment: edite la ultima respuesta, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para.. como hacer un SP es una pregunta muyyyyyy distinta a la que estas haciendo aca.. Aca estas preguntando como escribir el sql para que te de el resultado que queres... vos queres un SP para conseguir eso? como se pasan parametros y esas cosas? creo que tendrias que haber empezado por ahi de ser necesario...

Comment: Algo así como una consulta genérica que me pueda devolver el resultado deseado

Comment: Paul, la pregunta que esta escrita ahi arriba, aunque tenia una etiqueta php, no habia ni una linea de codigo de php y solo preguntaba como solucionar el query. Si le pasas el parametro que vos queres, la consulta ya esta. Cual es la verdadera pregunta aca?